# Entity Framework Check Nested Null Objects

Tags: linq, frameworks, entity

I am using entity framework LINQ to dispaly department,process and check info. Each Department has multiple process and each process can have multiple check. I want to dipslay the data in a manner that department will be display only once for multiple processs, and for each process check should be displayed in front of the process.

Here is the example.

---

### | Deptarment | Process     | Checks              |

### | Dept 1     | Process A   | Check A

### |------------|-------------| Check B

### | Dept 2     | Process B   | Check A

### |------------|-------------| Check B

### |------------|-------------| Check C

### |------------|-------------| Check D

### | Dept 3     | Process A   | Check A

### |------------|-------------| Check A

### | Dept 4     | Process A   | Dept 4  SHOULD NOT BE Displayed In my Case

### |------------|-------------|  As it doesn't have any check info.

```
    [WebMethod]
// [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string GetDataEntryList(int companyId)
{
    VisioneEntities vEntity = new VisioneEntities();
    var retValue =
                (from dept in vEntity.Departments
                 join prooo in vEntity.Processes on dept.DepartmentId equals prooo.DepartmentId
                 select new
                 {
                     DepartmentId = dept.DepartmentId,
                     DepartmentName = dept.DepartmentName,
                     DataEntryProcessInfoView = (from pro in vEntity.Processes
                                                 where pro.DepartmentId == dept.DepartmentId
                                                 select new DataEntryProcessInfo()
                                                 {
                                                     ProcessId = pro.ProcessID,
                                                     ProcessName = pro.ProcessName,
                                                     DataEntryCheckInfos = from chk in vEntity.ProcessChecks
                                                                           where chk.ProcessId == prooo.ProcessID
                                                                           select new DataEntryCheckInfo() { CheckId = chk.CheckId, CheckName = chk.CheckName, Frequency = chk.Frequency }
                                                 }
                                    )
                 }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new DataEntryInfoView() { DepartmentId = x.DepartmentId, DepartmentName = x.DepartmentName, DataEntryProcessInfos = x.DataEntryProcessInfoView });

    //var filterItems=from ret in retValue
    //                select new {r1=ret.DepartmentId,r2=ret.DataEntryProcessInfos.Select

    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(retValue.AsEnumerable());

    return json;


}
```

Below are the classes i have used.

```
    public class DataEntryInfoView
    {

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public DataEntryCheckInfo checkInfo;
    public IQueryable<DataEntryProcessInfo> DataEntryProcessInfos;
    }

    public class DataEntryCheckInfo
    {
    public int CheckId { get; set; }
    public string CheckName { get; set; }
    public string Frequency { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataEntryProcessInfo
    {
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public string ProcessName { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<DataEntryCheckInfo> DataEntryCheckInfos; 
    }
```

Here is the result i don't want to dipslay those records which don't have  DataEntryCheckInfo is null

Below is the result i am getting

```
    {"d":"[{\"DataEntryProcessInfos\":[{\"DataEntryCheckInfos\":[{\"CheckId\":21,\"CheckName\":\"Fahad     \",\"Frequency\":\"Weekly\"},{\"CheckId\":22,\"CheckName\":\"Fahad     \",\"Frequency\":\"Weekly\"},{\"CheckId\":63,\"CheckName\":\"Check Test\",\"Frequency\":\"Fortnightly\"}],\"ProcessId\":7,\"ProcessName\":\"Process 1\"}],\"DepartmentId\":2,\"DepartmentName\":\"Dept 2\"},{\"DataEntryProcessInfos\":[{\"DataEntryCheckInfos\":[{\"CheckId\":86,\"CheckName\":\"afdassd   \",\"Frequency\":\"Yearly\"}],\"ProcessId\":8,\"ProcessName\":\"Wasqur Process\"}],\"DepartmentId\":7,\"DepartmentName\":\"Dept 6\"},{\"DataEntryProcessInfos\":[{\"DataEntryCheckInfos\":[{\"CheckId\":65,\"CheckName\":\"New Check \",\"Frequency\":\"Weekly\"},{\"CheckId\":66,\"CheckName\":\"abc       \",\"Frequency\":\"Monthly\"},{\"CheckId\":67,\"CheckName\":\"2333      \",\"Frequency\":\"Weekly\"},{\"CheckId\":84,\"CheckName\":\"adafdasdfs\",\"Frequency\":\"Fortnightly\"},{\"CheckId\":85,\"CheckName\":\"Test check\",\"Frequency\":\"Fortnightly\"}],\"ProcessId\":9,\"ProcessName\":\"Process 2 Wasqur\"},{\"DataEntryCheckInfos\":[{\"CheckId\":65,\"CheckName\":\"New Check \",\"Frequency\":\"Weekly\"},{\"CheckId\":66,\"CheckName\":\"abc       \",\"Frequency\":\"Monthly\"},{\"CheckId\":67,\"CheckName\":\"2333      \",\"Frequency\":\"Weekly\"},{\"CheckId\":84,\"CheckName\":\"adafdasdfs\",\"Frequency\":\"Fortnightly\"},{\"CheckId\":85,\"CheckName\":\"Test check\",\"Frequency\":\"Fortnightly\"}],\"ProcessId\":14,\"ProcessName\":\"My New Procees\"}],\"DepartmentId\":8,\"DepartmentName\":\"Dept 7\"},{\"DataEntryProcessInfos\":[{\"DataEntryCheckInfos\":[{\"CheckId\":68,\"CheckName\":\"CHeck 1   \",\"Frequency\":\"Weekly\"},{\"CheckId\":73,\"CheckName\":\"New Check \",\"Frequency\":\"Fortnightly\"},{\"CheckId\":74,\"CheckName\":\"Checker   \",\"Frequency\":\"Weekly\"},{\"CheckId\":77,\"CheckName\":\"Wasi      \",\"Frequency\":\"Weekly\"}],\"ProcessId\":10,\"ProcessName\":\"My New Process\"},{\"DataEntryCheckInfos\":[{\"CheckId\":68,\"CheckName\":\"CHeck 1   \",\"Frequency\":\"Weekly\"},{\"CheckId\":73,\"CheckName\":\"New Check \",\"Frequency\":\"Fortnightly\"},{\"CheckId\":74,\"CheckName\":\"Checker   \",\"Frequency\":\"Weekly\"},{\"CheckId\":77,\"CheckName\":\"Wasi      \",\"Frequency\":\"Weekly\"}],\"ProcessId\":12,\"ProcessName\":\"Tes\"}],\"DepartmentId\":13,\"DepartmentName\":\"Dept 11\"},{\"DataEntryProcessInfos\":[{\"DataEntryCheckInfos\":[],\"ProcessId\":11,\"ProcessName\":\"222\"}],\"DepartmentId\":15,\"DepartmentName\":\"Dept 13\"},{\"DataEntryProcessInfos\":[{\"DataEntryCheckInfos\":[],\"ProcessId\":10,\"ProcessName\":\"My New Process\"},{\"DataEntryCheckInfos\":[],\"ProcessId\":12,\"ProcessName\":\"Tes\"}],\"DepartmentId\":13,\"DepartmentName\":\"Dept 11\"},{\"DataEntryProcessInfos\":[{\"DataEntryCheckInfos\":[],\"ProcessId\":13,\"ProcessName\":\"33\"}],\"DepartmentId\":14,\"DepartmentName\":\"Dept 12\"},{\"DataEntryProcessInfos\":[{\"DataEntryCheckInfos\":[],\"ProcessId\":9,\"ProcessName\":\"Process 2 Wasqur\"},{\"DataEntryCheckInfos\":[],\"ProcessId\":14,\"ProcessName\":\"My New Procees\"}],\"DepartmentId\":8,\"DepartmentName\":\"Dept 7\"}]"}
```

On more thing if you can help me out i wan to bind this data using Jquery Template but i don't want to use nested table as it will create problems for fluid templates as well as header will not be display properly. here is my template in the above question.

```
 <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="btn-group  row-fluid" style="margin-top: 4px">
            <button class="btn">
                ${DepartmentId}</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success">
                    ${DepartmentName}</button></div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="4">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" border="0" cellspancing="0"
            cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%">
            {{each DataEntryProcessInfos}}<tr>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    <div class="btn-group row-fluid" style="margin-top: 4px">
                        <button class="btn">
                            ${ProcessId}</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-warning">
                                ${ProcessName}</button></div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 60%">
                    <table style="width: 100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable">
                        {{each DataEntryCheckInfos}}<tr>
                            <td style="width: 33%">
                                <div class="btn-group row-fluid" style="margin-top: 4px">
                                    <button class="btn">
                                        ${CheckId}</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger">
                                            ${CheckName}</button></div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 33%">
                                <button class="btn">
                                    ${Frequency}
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 33%">
                                <a class="btn-link" href="CheckItems.aspx?checkId=${CheckId}&mode=entry">Action
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {{/each}}
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested objects are never null. They are `IEnumerable`. But I think you want the items where the nested collections are not empty:

```
retvalue = retvalue.Where(x => x.DataEntryProcessInfoView.Any(
                               y => y.DataEntryCheckInfos.Any());
```

where `retvalue` is the part before `AsEnumerable().Select(x => new DataEntryInfoView()...`.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have explain my question now. I will try you suggestion now and get back in few minutes. thanks for your time.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked can you explain me how it works?

Comment: `Any()` looks if there is at least one element in the collection you specify by its argument. So you look for the items that have at least one `DataEntryProcessInfoView` object with at least one `DataEntryCheckInfos` object.

Comment: On more thing if you can help me out i wan to bind this data using Jquery Template but i don't want to use nested table as it will create problems for fluid templates as well as header will not be display properly. here is my template in the above question

Comment: Not my expertise. But feel free to post a new question if you get stuck on it.

Comment: I mean a new post, not an edit. According to StackOverflow's Q&A format a post should contain one question so it can have one accepted answer. Would you mind moving the appended part to a new question?